# Display one imageview(visible & invisible) for three time in android

Tags: android, timer, imageview

I want to show an image view for three like on/off,if any one have idea how to display an imageview for three time.I am using below code for these

```
 totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 180 * 1000;     
 timeBlinkInMilliseconds = 60 * 1000;
    private  boolean blink=true;
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds,500) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
           if ( leftTimeInMilliseconds < timeBlinkInMilliseconds ) {
                if (blink) {
                    handImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    handImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                blink = !blink;     
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            handImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }.start();
```

Please help,Thank in advance :)

Comment: You question is not clear at all! Exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to blink an imageview for three time

Comment: leftTimeInMilliseconds > timeBlinkInMilliseconds change less than to greater than

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create countDownTimer or anything.

Android provide you with nice alpha animation.

Here you go

**Java Code**

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AbcActivity.this, R.anim.blink);
myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
```

**blink.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:repeatCount="3"  <---- Image will blink 3 times
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

Comment: i want to invisible after three time

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer class

```
    autoUpdate = new Timer();
    autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    YourLogic();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 180 * 1000); // updates each 3 min
```

YourLogic function con be like this:

```
private void YourLogic() {
if ( leftTimeInMilliseconds < timeBlinkInMilliseconds ) {   
if (blink) {   
handImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
} else {    
handImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
}   
blink = !blink   
}
        }
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final AlphaAnimation  blinkanimation=   new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
blinkanimation.setDuration(300); // duration - half a second
blinkanimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
blinkanimation.setRepeatCount(3); // Repeat animation infinitely
blinkanimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

and set this animation to ur imageview as shown below

```
imageview.setAnimation(blinkanimation2);  or 
imageview.startAnimation(blinkanimation2);
```

change duration and repeatcount of animation according to ur requirement